# Рендеринг через js.haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, render

Есть скрипт

```
/content.js.haml

$("#articles").html("ssssss");
```

как засунуть в `.html()` вот это:

```
= render template: "shared/programms_show"
```

такие варианты не работают:

1.

```
/content.js.haml

:plain
 $("#articles").html("#{render template: 'shared/programms_show'}");
```

2.

```
/content.js.haml

 == $("#articles").html("#{render template: 'shared/programms_show'}");
```

Comment: А... для чего тут вообще HAML? Зачем натягивать шаблонизатор для XML и производных на не-XML?

Comment: да вот тоже непонятно, content.js.erb решило проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
:plain
  $("#articles").html("#{ escape_javascript( render template: 'shared/programms_show' ) }");
```

`escape_javascript` - экранирует кавычки и переносы строк в отрендеренном HTML.

Так же у этого метода есть алиас `j`.
То есть можно так:

```
:plain
  $("#articles").html("#{ j( render template: 'shared/programms_show' ) }");
```